# MSTeams Config page Angular 12 SPA with routing

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm using Angular 12 and am writing a simple group tab app.   I'm working on the config page component and the html looks like this:

```
<br />
<br />
<br />
<p>Configuration 3</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="Some Test" />
```

In a normal browser, the text and box appears.   But if I try to do the same thing via the install to tab path, I don't get the text or input box at all.

I think this might have something to do with routing but can't confirm.

The app-routing-module is pretty simple:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'configuration',
    component: ConfigurationComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      initialNavigation:
        !BrowserUtils.isInIframe() && !BrowserUtils.isInPopup()
          ? 'enabled'
          : 'disabled',
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

So what does it take to get the SPA to route to the configuration page when used within teams?

Configuration Component:  (URL purposed changed to protect the innocent)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Inject, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import * as microsoftTeams from '@microsoft/teams-js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-configuration',
  templateUrl: './configuration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./configuration.component.scss'],
})
export class ConfigurationComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,
    private elementRef: ElementRef
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    microsoftTeams.initialize();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('Initializing ms teams');

    microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnSaveHandler((saveEvent) => {
      microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
        entityId: '',
        contentUrl: 'https://test.ngrok.io',
        suggestedDisplayName: 'Test',
        websiteUrl: 'https://test.ngrok.io',
      });
      saveEvent.notifySuccess();
    });

    console.log('Register on save');
    microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true);
  }
}
```

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Hello, Are you trying to show it in static tab or config tab? Please have a look at [Tab-requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tab-requirements).

Answer (score 0):

In order to render a tab in Teams. You need to make sure that it is iFramable. Please see the document- [Tab requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tab-requirements).

Make sure that you have given the domain in [valid domains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#validdomains) in your manifest.

*Please share more details like console error, what are you using static tab or config and manifest, if issue isn't solve for you*

Comment: I don't think that's the issue.   It more seems that if I've got parts in a component (angular 12), that those components don't render as expected.   I added the configuration component above.

Comment: Please share more details like console error? Could you please confirm on Tab requirements?

Comment: All tab requirements have been met, when I go through a browser, my console is so full of error messages of one kind or another, that it is essentially useless.
I burned down the whole thing and started over.   With a simple app, it appears that I have it working, but it is incredibly slow the first time.   I'm not really downloading that much in the way of code either.   Details to follow.

Comment: Please share the manifest Also, please make sure you have defined the content URL in configurableTabs section of Manifest?

Comment: I found out that it has nothing to do with my routing at all.
There are 2 areas causing me problems.  The first is the initialNavigation: section above and the second is when I put MsalAngular into the app.component.ts constructor.  If I do any of that, I get nothing in my teams app.

Answer (score 0):

I traced my problem for this particular question to the line:

```
  initialNavigation:
    !BrowserUtils.isInIframe() && !BrowserUtils.isInPopup()
      ? 'enabled'
      : 'disabled',
```

This example is in a lot of the code for SPAs in and Teams Tabs.

I just have it set to 'enabled' for now and I can get beyond the purpose of this question.